# "Dim X as Y", How to Define Variables From Type NAMES

Tags: vb.net

Can I Define Variables From Type NAMES, I mean can I have a function that return's me
a Type Name (like integer), and I will define a Variable as the type name the function return's

Can I do It ?, If yes How ?

Code Example :

```
Public Function WhatIsTheType(ByVal num As Integer) as <I Dont Know What Comes Here>
    If num = 1 Then
        Return Int
    ElseIf num = 2 Then
        Return String
    ElseIf num = 3 Then
        Return Char
    End If
    Return Object
End Function

Public Sub main()
    Dim y As Integer = 2
    Dim X As WhatIsTheType(y)
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you are asking if you can test a variable to see what type it is, like is it a string, int, array etc. However, you example sets the variable Y as an integer, so the WhatIsTheType function is not testing anything. Also, you would just have WhatIsTheType(ByVal y As Integer). maybe explain further and I can help

Comment: No, I dont want to test a variable to see what type it is, I want Do return the Type Name And Define The var From the Type Name.

Comment: you can get the type of a variable with:

Comment: you can get the type of a variable with: .getType() like num.getType() ; but there may not be a need--is most cases the variable will take the type of the value fed into it.

Comment: you could compare the num with something like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/R2LkDs then on return, you could convert your variable based on the return value - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bzk8e8c(v=vs.90).aspx  seems like an odd situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of Type-expressions *cannot* be used as types in code. Types that appear in code (eg. the type of a variable) *must* refer to an actual type at time of compilation and *cannot* depend upon run-time values or computations.

So even if it is declared as `Function WhatIsTheType(..) As Type` (see the [Type class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx)) it is *useless* in trying to apply the *actual* type (represented by the return Type-value) to a variable declaration.

Without further unification the best that can be said is `Dim x As Object` (that is the static type *cannot* be refined further), which isn't very fun to deal with.